Android studio code .The emulator process of avd terminated
whenever i run avd.it says emulator process of avd terminated.ied to find the main problem in logs and found "The system cannot find the file specified. (2)"this error ..what to do? please help.
INFO - Emulator: Pixel_8_Pro_API_35 - [14252:8892:20240831,200730.248:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\muyaz\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.1.20.db\attachments\3a459550-4913-4c26-8835-a0b6a6e2c9c8: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
this is the problem
my sdk location is in C:\Users\muyaz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
and android studio location is in C:\programfiles\android\Androidstudio
whenever i run avd.it says emulator process of avd terminated.ied to find the main problem in logs and found "The system cannot find the file specified. (2)"this error
